# Get the reverse formula for another column based on existing column's formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of base price but don’t have the list price. Below are the formulas under column W and column AN.

Formulas:

W: =ROUND(T3+(ROUND(T3*V3,2)),2)

AN: =ROUND(W3-(ROUND( (ROUND(W3*Y3,2)) + (ROUND(W3*AD3,2)),2)),2)

In order to get the list price, I need to use trial and error method to find out the list price for each items and yet I have 7000+ lines of them. Therefore, is that any possible way to reverse the formula or create a new formula in column T so that I no longer need to try one by one to find the correct price for each item.
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evoir.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could work the algebra to solve for T from AN. Can you check the formulas provided? It looks like a quantity or tax or something is missing from the formula for W (it's 3x the indicated answer from the formulas provided for row 3).

The algebra (if you can ignore rounding) can simplify as follows: 
    W = T+(TV) => 
    W=T*(1+V)

```
AN = W - (WY + W*AD) => 
AN = W - W*(Y+AD) => 
AN = W*(1-Y-AD) =>
AN = T*(1+V) * (1-Y-AD) => 
T=AN/((1+V)*(1-Y-AD))
```

So, you have T4=AN4/((1+V4)*(1-Y4-AD4)).

Considering the rounding--you're probably still going to have an issue because of the Y and AD discounts being individually rounded. It happens to work for A1, but not sure if it'll work throughout... I'd plan on a missing penny here or there.

```
(AN7+ROUND((Y7+AD7)*AN7/(1-(Y7+AD7)),2))-ROUND(V7*(AN7+ROUND((Y7+AD7)*AN7/(1-(Y7+AD7)),2))/(1+V7),2)
```

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake on copy and paste. I'd uploaded a new sample data. The algebra was created by the seniors and I am advised not to make any changes on it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah. Updates make more sense. that formula for T4 will get you there without rounding. Give me a few minutes and I'll have the rounding

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why AE appears in the formula cause Column AE has its own data which use to get values for column AO. My assignment is to find the List price (column T) and if I delete the formulas for W or AN is it possible to have any algebra or formula to get values in column T directly? I have the numbers for column AN actually.

Comment: Good catch. Corrected AN to AE